# Sonarqube upgrade on Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure-sql-database

At present one of our ACI (SonarQube 7.7 community edition) is running with Azure SQL Server DB. Now I need to map existing Azure SQL Server database to a new ACI (SonarQube 7.9.6 community edition). I had done but ACI is not running properly and some times events/logs are not stored, and I even tired with to stop & deleted ACI (SonarQube 7.7 community edition) as well.

At our end my main priority is need to upgrade SonarQube version 7.7 to 7.9.X or newer.

Is it possible to upgrade the sonarqube image in the same ACI?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to upgrade the sonarqube and here ate the steps to upgrade the Snoarqube.

- Download and unzip the SnorQube distribution.
- If you're using third-party plugins, manually install plugins that are compatible with your version of SonarQube.
- Update the contents of `sonar.properties` and `wrapper.conf` files
- Stop your old server and start your new server.
- Browse to http://yourSonarQubeServerURL/setup and reanalyze your projects to get fresh data.

Here are the links which can give you complete information regarding SonarQube upgradation.
[Before you Upgrade.](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/before-you-upgrade/)

[Upgrade Guide.](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/upgrading/)