# IP address is not available anymore after updating a container instance

Tags: ip-address, azure-container-instances

I just try to update my existing container instance image using this command :

```
 az container create -g ressourcegroup --name sonar --image sonarqube:8.9-community --ports 9000 --location eastus --cpu 2 --memory 3.5
```

and it works fine, the image was updated, So I stopped the container instance manually then start it manually.

After starting the container instance the IP address disappear I don't know why while the status is Running.

Can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure IP address is available post update, use the `--ip-address` parameter in your existing command:

```bash
az container create -g ressourcegroup --name sonarqube --image sonarqube:8.9-community --ports 9000 --location eastus --cpu 2 --memory 3.5 --ip-address <Public/Private>
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Similarly, if you want to add additional parameters, for example how much CPU, Memory, port or any additional environment variables, you can add them accordingly, example-

```bash
az container create --<resource-group>  \  
--location <yourLocation> --name <ACIName> \  
--cpu <value> --memory <value> \  
--image sonarqube:8.9-community \  
--os-type Linux --ip-address Public \  
--environment-variables\  
'SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME'='sonar' \  
'SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD'='<your password>' \  
'SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL'='jdbc:sqlserver://srv-sql-sonarqube.database.windows.net:1433;database=sonarqubeDb;user=sonar@srv-sql-sonarqube;password=<your password>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30'\  
--ports 9000 \  
--protocol TCP
```

If your current ACI is not showing the IP address, then kindly check the JSON view for the ACI there should be IP Address section, Check if that is empty?

[image]

**Reference Document:**

[Azure Container Instance Documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/)

[SonarQube upgrade on ACI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71522946/sonarqube-upgrade-on-azure-container-instance)

[Deploy SonarQube on ACI](https://cristianonr.medium.com/using-sonarqube-in-azure-container-instances-46573de7233e)